# How to pass through USB device to guest VM? What are "hostaddr", "hostport" etc?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, qemu, arm, lsusb

I have the following on the host machine

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I would like second in a line device to be passed through to the machine.

Also

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 12M
```

What should I write in qemu command line? I wrote

```
-usb -hostbus=1 -hostport=3
```

and in failed to run with

```
qemu-system-arm: -hostbus=1: invalid option
```

---

I wrote

```
-usb \
-device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostport=3 \
```

And got

```
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/003: Permission denied
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/003: Permission denied
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
```

errors during boot under conventional used. If ran under `sudo` I got no errors, but also got no `USB` working under quest.

```
# lsusb
unable to initialize libusb: -99
```

Full command line

```
sudo qemu-system-arm \
    -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie \
    -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb \
    -serial stdio \
    -append "root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
    -hda myimage.img \
    -usb \
    -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostport=3 \
    -redir tcp:5022::22 \
    -redir tcp:5080::80 \
    -no-reboot
```

---

I have recompiled QEMU with

```
./configure --enable-libusb
```

but this didn't help. `lsusb` still gives an error. Also no rows about `usb` in `dmesg`. On real raspberri pi there are many `usb` rows including `dwc_otg`.

Comment: Partially. It doesn't work at least.

Comment: Now you have access errors which could be solved by using `udev` rules or by simply `chown`'ing files. Again, try googling first. You seem to be averse to finding answers on your own.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov the same image works normally under RaspberryPi why would I?

Comment: I don't know what "the same image" is and also I'm not sure you run `qemu` the same way on both systems. `sudo` will work for you 100%.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov tried `sudo`, see section "full command line"